# Is it possible to include aria2 in my project?

Tags: aria2

Is it possible to compile aria2 as a static library and use it in my Windows C ++ project, via the API? I did not find any information on this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible:
[libaria2: C++ library interface to aria2](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/libaria2.html) has a tutorial and API reference.

However, there's a warning:

> The API has not been frozen yet. It will be changed on the course of the development.

It just means that you may need to update your app when a new version is released.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not include the dll on Windows. Visual Studio could not find a function from the library. But I did everything I need through the RPC-interface.